# Using analytics.js in React without react-ga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I want to integrate google analytics into my react app without using the react-ga package. Specifically, I would like to be able to access the ga function within a react component. How do I get access to the ga function if I import the analytics.js script into my html? When I try to `console.log(window.ga)`, I am told it is undefined. Thanks!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(window.ga);
    return (
      <h1>This is a react app!</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script async src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the piece of code you should include:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

or this if you want to keep your link to the analytics.js

```
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Segment analytics library and following our [React quickstart guide](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react). You can track page visits with [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router) and user behavior all within React components using 1 single API. Here is an example of tracking a `User Signup` click using a React event handler:

```
export default class SignupButton extends Component {
  trackEvent() {
    window.analytics.track('User Signup');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.trackEvent}>
        Signup with Segment today!
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

I’m the maintainer of https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react. With Segment, you’ll be able to switch different destinations on-and-off by the flip of a switch if you are interested in trying multiple analytics tools (we support over 250+ destinations) without having to write any additional code.